# Use of WordPRess "X Theme" with CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, theme

In researching WordPress themes I find that the X Theme from ThemeForest.org is well-regarded, relatively easy to use, and very flexible in terms of resulting public facing website design / capability.

My question for the CiviCRM community is:  Does anyone out there have experience using WordPress / X Theme as a basis for implementing and running CiviCRM to provide integrated constituent management with a public facing website (that supports a not-for-profit organization)?

I've done the usual searches and so far turned up nada; so thanks for any insights that you can share with me (and this community).

If we go forward with this approach, I'll document it the same way I have documented the (successful) implementation of TLS secured [Ubuntu / LAMP / WordPress / CiviCRM](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=277970947) on Amazon Web Services.

Thanks for any insights you can provide.

DVH

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no." CiviCRM works with most themes, so I'd suggest you go ahead and try it.

Comment: Coleman, thanks for your comment.  We're not sure yet which theme we will use, but X is looking interesting.

Comment: We've been entertaining a switch from Salient to X because of a problem with some renderings, primarily on the "Manage Events -> Online Registration" bit.  I believe it was related to the "bootstrap" issues, as talked about here:  http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7885/why-do-field-labels-in-event-registration-forms-not-display-correctly/7886#7886  I thought I had another thread where this had been discussed, but I can't seem to find it now.  X didn't seem to exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Oops.  Actually, it was the backbone. classes causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed some quirks with how it handles the  wp_enqueue_media function. when we disabled that core function, some of the functionality started working.   I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: related: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/13045/certain-themes-break-wysiwyg-in-wordpress (also by @latinpolyguy)